# simple Javascript CSS opacity fade function

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

I have the following code:

```
<div id='icro' style="position:relative;left:-133px;float: left;top:-60px;opacity:0;">icro</div>
<script>
  var showicroDelay;
  showicro();
  function showicro() {
    document.getElementById('icro').style.opacity=parseInt(document.getElementById('icro').style.opacity) +.05;
    showicroDelay=setTimeout(showicro, 1);
    if (document.getElementById('icro').style.opacity==1) {
      clearTimeout(showicroDelay);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Can someone spot my mistake? I used basically the same code for moving an element and it worked flawlessly!
As of now, it only does it once, as in the opacity gets set to 0.05.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `parseInt` when you should be using `parseFloat` since opacity values are between 0 and 1.